# Notation for Nested Set

Tags: notation

Let $A=\{a,b\}$.  I'm looking for notation for $(A\times A)\;$,$\;(A\times A)\times (A\times A)$ , $((A\times A)\times (A\times A) )\times ((A\times A)\times (A\times A))$, and so on.

I don't think ${A^{2}}^{2}$ is a clear notation because this can be interpreted as being equal to $A^{4}=(A\times A\times A\times A\times A)$. By contrast, $(A^2)^2 \;$ is clearly equal to $\;(A\times A)\times (A\times A)$.

In general, I can write my set as $\overbrace{(((A^2)^2)^2...)}^{\text{n times}} \quad$, where I'm going to call $n$ the 'order' of the set.

I'm looking for a compact notation for this set.  I am considering this notation:
$A^{n:2} \equiv \overbrace{(((A^2)^2)...)}^{\text{n times}} \quad$.   Do you have a suggestion?

Also, I would like to know what to call an object like
$(((a,b),(a,a)),((b,b),(a,b)))$? I believe it is a kind of "tree". If I know what to call it, then I can hopefully go to the literature to see the work that has been done on these objects.  So, is it a tree or a nest or a hierarchy, ect.?  Thanks.

Comment: What is the difference of your sequence and $\displaystyle{A^{2^n}}$?

Comment: I might interpret $A^{2^2}$ as $A\times A \times A \times A$.  But clearly $((A)^2)^2$ = $(A \times A) \times ( A \times A)$.  In other words, $((a,b),(a,a)) $ belongs to  $((A)^2)^2$  but it does not belong to $A^{2^2}$.  And conversely, (a,b,a,a) belongs to  $A^{2^2}$ but not $((A)^2)^2$.

Comment: But they are canonically isomorphic as sets by sending $((w,x),(y,z))$ to $(w,x,y,z)$. I don't think there is someplace in mathematics that needs particular notion to distinguish them.

Comment: Hmmm...   $A\times (A \times A) \times A$ is also canonically isomorphic to $A \times A \times A \times  A$.   But if I give you $(a,b,b,a)$, then by itself you don't know whether this should be mapped to $(a,(b,b),a)$ or to $((a,b),(b,a))$.  In other words, I'm trying to make the argument that $(a,(b,b),a)$ contains more information than $(a,b,b,a)$.  That is somehow my intuition (but I am only a physicist).

Comment: >"I don't think there is a place in mathematics that needs to ... distinguish them."   In my work, I believe I do need to make this distinction, or at least it makes the work more efficient.  However, I will think more carefully about whether I really must make this distinction.

Comment: I think you can define the replacement operator $c$ recursively, too (see my answer). Clarify the meaning of "contains an $a$". In            $(  (((b,b),(b,b)), ((a,b),(b,b))) , \text{second element} )$ what do you replace the first element by?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps a straightforward recursive definition for a new operation (call it $!$ here) will work.

Define
$$
A^{!1} = A
$$
and for $n > 1$
$$
A^{!(n+1)} = A^{!n} \times A^{!n}
$$

With this definition the order (in your sense) of $A^{!n}$ is simply $n$.

Replace $!$ by any symbol you like.

Comment: Thanks Ethan.  I have a follow up question. I edited my original question and put a follow up question at the end.  I was wondering if you could take a look?

Comment: @Chris I doubt that structure has a name. Invent one in your document.